# If two random variables are Borel functions of each other, then conditioning on them has the same result

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose, random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Borel functions of each other. Is it true that $P(A|X_1) = P(A|X_2)$ a.s. ? I see such claims in Breiman.

Comment: If there exists Borel functions $u$ and $v$ such that $X_1=u(X_2)$ and $X_2=v(X_1)$, then $\sigma(X_1)=\sigma(X_2)$ and hence $P(A\mid X_1)=P(A\mid X_2)$ a.s. by definition.

Comment: @StefanHansen: In Breiman, it proves what you are saying using what I am saying, not the other way. That is confusing to me.

Comment: Breiman states that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables containing the same information, i.e. $\sigma(X_1)=\sigma(X_2)$, then $P(A\mid X_1)=P(A\mid X_2)$ a.s. He then states that $\sigma(X_1)=\sigma(X_2)$ implies that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are functions of each other (in fact these two conditions are equivalent).